# How can I remove an element that is NOT on the DOM using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to use jQuery to manipulate a cloned element that is not on the DOM, to perform actions like `.remove()` on it. Say I have the following code:

```js
var div= $('<div> <div id="div1"></div> </div>');
div.remove('#div1');
console.log(div.html());
```

The result on the console will still show that the element was not removed. `string` manipulation is not desirable, I'm looking for something analogue to `$().remove()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `div` variable will contain a reference to the outer `div`. You need to use `find()` to get the inner div by its `id`:

```
var $div = $('<div><div id="div1"></div></div>');
$div.find('#div1').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `context` argument of the [`jQuery()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/) function:

```
$('div', div).remove('#div1');
```